# Graphviz: displaying node attributes

Tags: python, graphviz

I need to display the attributes that were set for a node in GraphViz library.

```
from graphviz import Digraph
g = Digraph('G', filename='temp_graph.gv')
g.node(name='name', label='label', xlabel='xlabel', key1='value1', key2='value2')
g.view()
```

Currently, the result is as below. I need to show key1=value1 and key2=value2 also inside of the node.

Please let me know how may I display the graphviz node with its attributes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that what the label attribute is for?

```
from graphviz import Digraph


g = Digraph('G', filename='temp_graph.gv')
g.node(name='name', label='key1: {}\nkey2: {}'.format( 'value1', 'value2' ), xlabel='xlabel', key1='value1', key2='value2')
g.view()
```

If you need to save the 'label' you can set it to a different attribute on the node

```
g.node(name='name', label='key1: {}\nkey2: {}'.format( 'value1', 'value2' ), mylabel="label", xlabel='xlabel', key1='value1', key2='value2')
```

Comment: Thanks, this trick works :). However, my expectation was to get this result by different invocation of g.view() method, say g.viewWithAttr() or g.view(attr=true).